# Don't know how use 'serialize' method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, serialization

i have a model called user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :friends
end
```

when running the console script and create a new object of User class

```
user = User.new
user.friends
```

i found a 'NoMethodError'
should i write the serialize calling in another file?
OR what should i do to make the friends array an attribute for the User instance ?

Answer (score 4):

"serialize friends" will create a serialized attribute on **instances** of your model.

So you need to refer to the instance:

```
user = User.new
user.friends
```

Note the lower case on the second line - you need to refer to the instance held in the user variable.

Comment: sorry it was just a syntax error , actually i refer to the instance ,i have edited the original post .